# Save newly created object ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I'm using EF Code First and here is my class which references a Professor object.

```
public class Mark
    {
        public int MarkId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Grade")]
        [Display(Name = "Grade Value")]
        public int MarkValue { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide grade type")]
        [Display(Name = "Grade Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Subject")]
        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }


    }
```

In my view I have a dropdown to select a professor who put the mark.
I implemented it like this:

```
//controller
 public MarksController() : this(new MarkRepository())
        {
            IProfessorRepository professorsRepo = new ProfessorRepository();
            List<Professor> professors = professorsRepo.All.ToList<Professor>();

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (Professor p in professors)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Text = String.Concat(p.FirstName, " ", p.LastName), Value = p.ProfessorId.ToString() 
                });
            }

            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Please select Professor", Value = "0", Selected = true
            });

            ViewBag.Professors = items;
        }
//view create or edit
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MarkValue)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MarkValue)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MarkValue)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Professor)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Professors");
</div>
```

Yes, I know that there is is a metod in Controller called Create which appeals repository method InsertOrUpdate.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Mark mark)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                markRepository.InsertOrUpdate(mark);
                markRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } else {
                return View();
            }
        }


 public void InsertOrUpdate(Mark mark)
        {
            if (mark.MarkId == default(int)) {
                // New entity
                context.Marks.Add(mark);
            } else {
                // Existing entity
                context.Entry(mark).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

Everything seems logic, but how can I save a newly created Mark object with the professor selected? How does ASP.NET arranges the object which is passed to Create method on Controller? How should I match the selected professor with the mark I am creating?

Comment: Take a look at this, you need a ProfessorID in the model.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141714/model-binding-dropdown-selected-value

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this, you need a ProfessorId in the model.
[Model binding dropdown selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141714/model-binding-dropdown-selected-value)

```
public class Mark
{

    // this will hold the selected value

    public string ProfessorID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Professors
    { 
        get
        {
            return Proffessors                
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                    Value = x.ProfessorId.ToString(),
                    Text = String.Concat(p.FirstName, " ", p.LastName)
                });
        } 
    }

 public IEnumerable<Professor> Proffessors     
  {
     get
     {
         IProfessorRepository professorsRepo = new ProfessorRepository();
          return professorsRepo.All;
     }
 }

  //the rest of your code
}
```

in the view do

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ProfessorId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Professors, "Value", "Text")
)
```

Comment: Debug it why it is null. I didnt test it since I dont have your full code